# How to make the last keyframe of your animation "stay" after animation is finished

Tags: css, css-animations

I have tried many iterations of this, but it doesn't seem to want to just stay on the last keyframe.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<style>
#container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
#centerhex{
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/4sZDtfK.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center; 
height:224px;
width:210px;
position:absolute;
margin-left: -105px;
margin-top: -112px;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}   
.fadein{    
animation:fadein 1.5s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-delay:1s;
animation-fill-mode:forwards, none
animation-iteration-count: 1
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1
-webkit-animation:fadein 1.5s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards, none
}
.transtart{
opacity:0
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { 
0%{opacity:0;}
50%{opacity:1;}
60%{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:0.2;} 
}
@keyframes fadein {
0%{opacity:0;}
50%{opacity:1;}
60%{opacity:1;}
100%{opacity:0.2;} 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div class="fadein transtart">
    <div id="centerhex"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The animation fill should take care of it, but for some reason it's not.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Remove the dual declaration for `animation-fill-mode` is just `forwards` :

```
.fadein{    
  animation:fadein 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-delay:1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation:fadein 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/DR9Lu/6/

Comment: Thank you very much! It appears I left out some semicolons in my haste as well.